# Constantly being kinda logged off

Tags: support, login, google-chrome

Using Google Chrome (Dev channel), I experience that the system somehow logs me off 10-15 times a day. When returning to SO, I see this screen:

[image]

And after waiting a few seconds, I see this screen:

[image]

When I click the "**Click here**" button, I'm logged in again.

I already took a look at my cookies and found nothing which looks suspicious.

The behaviour first occurred apporx. 2-3 month ago. I also experience this on my iPad from time to time.

**My question:**

Any hints on how to keep being logged in all the time?

**Update 1:**

I've done a test with Firefox and Google Chrome. One log off in Google Chrome, none in Firefox.

Any ideas on how to hunt this down? Any cookies or anything I could inspect to see why the site sees me as logged off in Google Chrome?

**Update 2:**

It is getting worse; being logged off every half an hour or so. Doesn't happen on any other sites like Google Mail or Facebook where I assume they also use cookies to remember me.

**Update 3:**

Seems to increase, ever 10-20 minutes, never closing the browser, just the SO tab. Did again clear all "stack*" cookies without any improvement.

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue in any other browsers? Maybe you have some sort of privacy setting enables that clears cookies / session data?

Comment: @Cerbrus On my iPad (with Chrome) from time to time. I didn't do excessive testing with other browsers, I hoped that someone just tells me "Just do X and Y to solve". I'll test now.

Comment: If you switch devices/browsers where a "separate" login occurs you'll get these messages. If I login on my iPad and return to my laptop this message will appear.

Comment: I am experiencing identical behavior on iOS 8.

Comment: I experienced [some issues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258735/odd-website-behavior-on-stack-overflow-from-ios-8) that turned into what you describe once I updated to iOS 8 Beta 3.

Comment: @update3, Have checked the bug tracker/submitted a bug report for Chrome's dev build? Isn't that what it seems to be an issue with?

Comment: @indivisible I'm unsure; all other sites like Facebook, GMail etc. work. Should I really post this to Chrome's bug tracker?.

Comment: @UweKeim, if it is only happening on that browser (and version, did you try a stable build?) and if you have eliminated that it could be any add-ons interfering then yes, it's an issue for the Chrome devs. (Sidenote: Devs offer those types of "bleeding-edge" builds so that people *will* submit bug reports to help them test/iron out issues)

Answer (score 5):

Chances are, this is either some very old / corrupt cookies (fix by clearing your cookies) or an issue with dev-channel Chrome (no idea; can't test).

Comment: I was having this issue the other day; I'd click "refresh" but I was still logged out. Clearing cookies and starting over most definitely fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, Shog. I tried what you said, but still being logged of every two hours or so...

Comment: same thing is happening to me on 64-bit dev channel chrome, clearing cookies doesn't help with me either

Comment: I always have to clear my cookies _twice_ to fix the issue on iOS 8 (beta). And then it usually re-appears.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. I think I don't have the dev-channel Chrome (no idea what it is even). Is any resolution found other than clearing cookies? That really isn't much better than clicking log in and then immediately being recognized automatically.