# Why I am being automatically logged out of SO so often?

Tags: support, login, logout

For some reason, I can't seem to stay logged into SO for more than a few minutes. I am on MacOS 10.14.3, Safari 12.0.3. I've been on SO since the beginning, but this has only manifested recently (perhaps since Mojave's release last autumn, but I'm not certain). This appears to be only happening in Safari, but not Chrome.

I understand that this has come up in several related queries (e.g., [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262223/constantly-being-kinda-logged-off)) As per these answers, I have tried deleting cookies (from SO and from google since I am using that for identity). I have also tried turning off all of the tracking/cookies options under Safari>Preferences>Privacy. The problem resurfaces basically immediately in both cases.

(I have also whitelisted the site under the 1Blocker extension that I have running.)

Any ideas?

Comment: The post you link to doesn't have a resolution either to be honest, "clear the cookies" is just the usual cookie cutter answer (pun intended) and didn't seem to have helped anything. You have 18k rep so you are far from a newcomer, so this problem started happening only very recently right? Say... since a browser update maybe? Try in another browser to see if you can reproduce it there.

Comment: How are you logging in? If it's via Google, do you have Google settings to clear website associations automatically?

Comment: I do use Google -- where is the setting for "clear website associations"? Nowhere obvious in http://myaccount.google.com

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I though I saw one in there somewhere. I know there's a page that shows every site you're using Google login on. You could try removing SO from the list and then manually relogging in to see if that does anything.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe Security -> Signing in With Google -> Signing in With Google -> Stack Exchange -> Remove Access.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Signing in to other sites* I had to verify that Google didn't just repeated the same option twice.

Comment: Use the browser's devtools to see the request and response when you log in and then when the problem surfaces. Without that, we're stuck making blind guesses. `Cookie:` and `Set-Cookie:` headers are partcularly interesting.

Comment: Over the last couple of months, Stack Overflow appears to be logged out for me when I start my browser, even though I have turned on permanent cookies for the site. In fact, if I refresh the "logged-out" screen, the logged-in one then appears. I suspect a frontend proxy is caching something wrongly. I have been logged out mid-browsing session too, but usually that requires logging back in again.

Comment: Just as a data point, I'm on Mojave using Safari and don't have this problem. I'm on  Safari 12.0.1 not 12.0.3, so maybe that's a factor? I also browse exclusively in private browsing mode, so maybe another clue.

Comment: Are You browsing in *private* mode? Private browsing deletes all saved settings, the moment You close the tab or window. This effectively logs You out.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Does Safari actually remove site data after closing a tab, or only after the whole window is closed? I know Chrome only clears everything after all Incognito windows are closed.

Comment: @Clonkex depends on the user's personal browser settings.

Comment: Same thing started happening to me in last couple weeks after no logout issues for years.  Mac OS 10.13.6 and Safari 12.0.3

Comment: Anything new on this?  I can confirm that I've repeatedly cleared out cookies, etc. and yet every few days being prompted for login.  Certainly, something to do with logins has been changed on this site?

Comment: @Sparky It's a Safari bug. I haven't been able to use Safari since Mojave as cookies are deleted every few minutes even while I'm using the website. There is no solution. Safari Technology Preview is not affected so you can use that.

Comment: @Monstieur, thank you.  I'm using Safari in High Sierra though.  It might stay logged in for many days before the problem happens, not every few minutes.

Comment: I am using Chrome in Mojave. And, this is happening to me. This completely resets my Fanatic achievement as well :/